# Bootstrap 4 carousel streching images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm having a few issues with a simple carousel that uses bootstrap 4.The carousel has 3 images with the class `d-block w-100` which i guess should stretch the image to the whole width of the screen but it looks like for me the image goes a little bit out of the screen and i don't understand why it does that and how should i prevent it from doing that?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.besthdwallpaper.com/download/urus-lamborghini-wallpaper-1920x600-1843_57.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.besthdwallpaper.com/download/bmw-i8-wallpaper-1920x600-2712_57.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://imagescdn.dealercarsearch.com/DealerImages/ImageLibrary/1920x600/2013-Honda-Accord.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, it looks like this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .row in bootstrap is giving a margin right and left of -15px and that's the one creating a scrollbar on the bottom. Just add a "no-gutters" to your row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.besthdwallpaper.com/download/urus-lamborghini-wallpaper-1920x600-1843_57.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.besthdwallpaper.com/download/bmw-i8-wallpaper-1920x600-2712_57.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://imagescdn.dealercarsearch.com/DealerImages/ImageLibrary/1920x600/2013-Honda-Accord.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```